# R segmented package "variable lengths differ"

Tags: r

I'm having trouble getting started with the segmented package in R.

When running the basic example below I get the error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x + U1.x + psi1.x, data = mfExt,  : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'x')

I was expecting segmented to return a piecewise linear model with 2 segments. I'm clearly making a mistake in my call, but am unable to work out from the error message and the documentation what my mistake is. Help would be appreciated.

```
require(segmented)

test.df = data.frame(x = c(1:100),
                  y = c(c(1:50),seq(from = 52, by = 2, length = 50)))

test.mod = lm(y ~ x,
              test.df)

segmented(test.mod,
          seg.Z = ~ x,
          psi = list(x = 40))
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with your example. Only get a warning `essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had an object in my workspace called 'x'. After removing this object the call to segmented gave expected results.

I can replicate the error any time I have an object of length 1 called x regardless of whether that object is a list or a vector.

If the object has length greater than 1, the error disappears and segmented behaves as expected.

Weird. Thanks @Pascal for your input.